# How to send data from array to socket.io one by one

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have array that have 1000 object inside when user connect to website I want to send him this data one by one. But unfortunately this code doesn't work.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
   console.log('made socket connection');

  for(i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    socket.emit('initial', data[i]);
  }
});
```

When I open browser I need to wait 1.5s and then I'm receiving all data. Do you have any idea how to received this data one by one, to be in real-time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found way how to achieve that. I think that because I send so many data in the same time on the stock browser was not able to refresh and after 1 second (adding all data) browser made refresh and all data appear.  I not sure if my understanding is correct. But here is code that I added to make it works.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
 console.log('made socket connection');
 var senddata = function(i){

    if(i<data.length){
        socket.emit('initial', data[i], function(confirmation){
            i++       
            senddata(i);
        });
    }
 }
 senddata(0);
}
```

So how you see I’m waiting for callback, so now I see that data appear one by one. But because of callback so request client-server and server-client it take a little more time to load all data in the browser. That’s is way I changed approach to  send partial data to browser and make only few callback not for each array data. I wrote simple function to split array on few smaller one, so now we split the work between the browser and the server.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) =>{
 console.log('made socket connection');
 function sendinit(start, jump){
    var last = start+jump;
    if(last<data.length){
        socket.emit('initial', data.slice(start,last), function(confirmation){
            sendinit(last,jump);
        });
    }
    else if(last>=data.length){
        socket.emit('initial', data.slice(start,data.length), function(confirmation){
            console.log('data have been sent');
        });
    }
 }
 sendinit(0,200);
}
```

I'm waiting for your comments, what do you think about this approach?